# Difference between 'generic' and 'method'?

Tags: r, r-s3

I noticed that the following functions in R have two slightly different classifications:

```r
sloop::ftype(t.test)
#> [1] "S3"      "generic"

sloop::ftype(t.data.frame)
#> [1] "S3"     "method"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

One is a 'generic' and one is a 'method' but I'm struggling to differentiate the two: my understanding of a 'generic' is that it *is* a method - specifically, a method which acts on an input object according to its class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method *implements* a generic (or, on a more technical level, a method gets called by a generic via `UseMethod`).

That is, a generic function calls `UseMethod`; it might look something like this:

```
foo = function (x, ...) UseMethod('foo')
```

Whereas a *method* is a function that implements the generic for a specific S3 class; for instance:

```
foo.bar = function (x, ...) message('class of x is bar!')
```

Comment: Ah I see! So in your example, you've defined an implementation of the generic `foo` for the S3 class `bar`? And you could write more implementations of the generic for other S3 classes too, right?

Comment: @Johnny Yes, exactly.